# Como retorna múltiplos objetos numa função do r?

Tags: r, funções

A estrutura básica de uma função no R é:

```
function( arglist ) expr
return(value)
```

A minha questão é de como retornar múltiplas informações. Por exemplo:

```
funcao<-function(a,b,c){
 if(c==1){d<-a+b}
 else{d<-a-b}
return(d)
}
```

O quero saber é como posso agregar mais informações no return. 
Assim teria:

```
exemplo<-funcao(1,2,1)
>exemplo
3
>exemplo$metodo
"soma"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Se você quiser retornar mais de um objeto, você deve utilizar uma `list()`:

```
         f <- function(a, b, c) {
  d <- a + (b * c)
  return(list(a = a, b = b, c = c, d = d))
}


f(2, 4, 6)
# $a
# [1] 2
# 
# $b
# [1] 4
# 
# $c
# [1] 6
# 
# $d
# [1] 26

f(2, 4, 6)$d
# [1] 26
```